# How to close html tags inputed by the user. ie closing the tag automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need some help here...

How to close html tags inputed by a user??

Suppose he types:

```
<html>
```

I want the program to close it like:

```
<html></html>
```

another eg,

Input:`<body>`

Output:`<body></body>`

EDIT:

Suppose the user is continuously typing..(coding html).How do i get his code then and there and close it immediately after he opens a tag..(There will be a lot of tags which he would have inputted and i  want it  to close then and there)

Wrapping up my edit:

**I want the program close html tags like it  happens in jsfiddle ..**

Hope i was clear with the question...

Thanks in advance,

Sangamesh

Comment: I am just looking out for some ideas.or  some open source parses

Comment: any ideas on how  to achieve this using js or jquery..

Comment: Start from [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), combine the event with [Textarea Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) ...

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for automatic tag close which really save time and error use editor.If you are an linux user use sublime or atom.If you are an windows user use editplus.If you use MAC use coteditor.These are also serve good replacement for default text editor.

Comment: I am asking how to close tags automatically..i am not asking where i could get this ..i am asking "how"

Answer (score 0):

You can put up something that parses the  into element alone. Say that a string is an array of characters, therefore you can trim the string starting from index 1 (second character), then to the previous character before the last element. We expect the first character in index 0 to be < and the last character in the index (varname.length) to be >, hence we trim it from index 1 and to the index varname.length - 1 to extract what's inside the <> and to get the element name to be returned.

As a pseudo-code:

```
// say the user's input was assigned to variable inputValue
var elementName = inputValue.substring(1, length-1); 
// Now element's name holds what's inside the brackets <xxx>
var finalReturn = inputValue + "</" + elementName + ">";
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the DOM element

2) Get HTML from DOM element

```
$("<html>")[0].outerHTML
//"<html></html>"

$("<table><tr><td>hi<td>hi")[0].outerHTML
//"<table><tbody><tr><td>hi</td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>"
```